# How to handle RadioButton checked event in Preferences?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-preferences

I want my listview in sorted order as selected option from Preferences that i created so can any tell me or provide me a code to handle the check event of radio button??
[image]

```
 <PreferenceCategory
   android:summary="Sorting Order"
   android:title="Sort By" >

  <ListPreference
 android:entries="@array/listOptions"
 android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
 android:key="listpref"
 android:summary="Sorting Values"
 android:title="Sort Order" />
 </PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your activity, you would have it implement the SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener and implement the method:

```
onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html

For example:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key != null) {
          if (key.contentsEquals("your_key_value_within_preferences") {
             //Stuff to do based on changes in preferences
          }
        }
}
```

Though it may differ from your application, check out the CubeLiveWallpaper example from the Google Android examples, as it has a thorough implementation.